# How to "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1" in Laravel Join statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

when i try to execute DB query with 6 Joins i get following error message:

> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1104 The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay`

```
 $results = DB::table('table_1')
->join('table_2', 'table_1.id', '=', 'table_2.id')
```

...

My question is:
**How i can set "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1" in laravel query?**

Answer (score 6):

i found a solution :)

> in app/config/database.php

change following:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

To:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'options'   => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1',
        ),
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

I added the "options" array and define SQL_BIG_SELECTS

Thats it, we can configure PDO in any way we need!

Hope this is usefull to other ;)