# MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 - script stop working after 2 years

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
Exception -> string(69) "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1193 Unknown system variable 'OPTION'" Exception -> string(202) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
 access violation: 1104 The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if 
the SELECT is okay" Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1104 The SELECT 
would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay' in 
/customers/e/3/b/jkr.no/httpd.www/STS/amob/inc/timer.php:295 Stack trace: #0 
/customers/e/3/b/jkr.no/httpd.www/STS/amob/inc/timer.php(295): unknown() #1 /customers/e/3/b/jkr.no/httpd.www/STS/amob/index.php(542): 
include('/customers/e/3/...') #2 {main} thrown in /customers/e/3/b/jkr.no/httpd.www/STS/amob/inc/timer.php on line 295
```

This script been working fine for 2 years. I deleted over 2000 lines in the active table, maybe its too big?

SQL-Question

```
$hsql = "SELECT h.ID, h.ukeID, h.normal, h.natt, h.FP, h.HP, h.datumID, h.status, h.orderID, 
h.tilleggID, h.yearID, u.ID as userID, u.level as ulevel, 
u.navn as fnavn, u.etternavn, t.navn as tnavn, o.ID as oID, o.navn as onavn,
 o.pH as opH, o.pB as opB, o.pR as opR, o.pS as opS, o.pP as opP, o.pLE as opLE 
FROM timesheet h LEFT JOIN user u ON u.ID = h.userID LEFT JOIN orders o ON
 o.ordernr = h.orderID LEFT JOIN tillegg t ON t.tilleggnr = h.tilleggID AND 
t.orderID = o.ID".$hsql.$sstr.$yearID."  ORDER BY userID ASC, yearID DESC, ukeID DESC, datumID DESC";
```

Line 295

```
foreach($hstmt as $hrow) {
```

Comment: Where have you added the `SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1`?

Comment: First line
`code`
$bisql = "SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1";
try {
 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
 $bistmt = $dbh->prepare($bisql);
 $bistmt->execute(array( ));
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception -> ';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
`code`

Comment: I think you need to set it as an option when calling the generating code. Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853129/how-to-set-sql-big-selects-1-in-laravel-join-statement

Comment: I replaced SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 with SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1
Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Switched

```
SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1
```

to

```
SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1
```

Now it works!